# Using threads in Rails Observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, thread-safety, observer-pattern

As far as I know Observer pattern in Ruby on Rails is not made to be asynchronous meaning that Observer's execution will block the action being processed.

I know about delayed_job gem and I really like it but sometimes it looks a bit too heavy for certain purposes.

What about launching a new thread in the Observer's callback?

I spent some time trying to find pros and cons of such approach and failed.

So the question is: are there any serious drawbacks of Observer's threading?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)? It's the new "hot" gem to do background processing (vs resque or delayedjob).

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ):

> sidekiq uses redis for storage and processes messages in a multi-threaded process.
>   It's just as easy to set up as resque but more efficient in terms 
>   raw processing speed. Your worker code does need to be thread-safe.

There's also a railscast about it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).

I would recommend using that compared to creating your own thread.

Comment: I have heard of it and it looks cool but it doesn't answer my question)

Comment: No idea about the technical drawbacks, sorry. I dont know to what extend you'd like to use this method. It just feels cumbersome, more error-prone, difficult to use etc.

Answer (score 0):

DelayedJob and Sidekiq both present good options, and Rails offers full ActiveJob support now, here are the official docs - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_job_basics.html

DelayedJob I *think* has been around the longest, created by the crew that built Shopify.com.  It creates a table in your rails app and queues and works off of that.  For me it provides the simplest option, as it carries no other dependencies other than your rails app.

Sidekiq offers a great alternative as well.   It too is very simple and well-maintained, but instead of using your database, it uses a redis server to manage the jobs.  That makes development a bit trickier, as you have to install redis and remember to start it when running your app.  Not hard, just a bit extra stuff.

Here's a quick guide comparing the two - [DelayedJob vs. Sidekiq](https://www.sqlbot.co/blog/delayed-job-vs-sidekiq-which-one-should-you-choose), hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your opinion. Initially when I asked that question I thought it was obvious that I did not want any additional tables in my DB or additional backend in my infrastructure. I think that the answer to my question would be something like "It depends on which ruby you are using. Since mri ruby is single threaded you will achieve nothing. But if you switch to jruby, you can get some benefits out of it"